# javascript: multidimensional array manipulation

Tags: javascript

I have something like this (data should be a global variable):

```
var data = {
    fields:{
      id: 0,
      ticket: 0,
      description: 0,
    }
}
```

Now I want to use something like this to change these variables:

```
function toggleStatus(element) {
data[fields][element] = 1;
}
```

This doesn't work, of course, but what is the correct way to manipulate data in similar fashion?

Basically, I need to create a multidimensional array that changes it's status based on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine, but you have to enclose `fields` in quotes:

```
data['fields'][element] = 1;
```

Or

```
data.fields[element] = 1;
```

Comment: In addition, you can do:

    data.fields.element = 1;

Comment: @Shadowedged -- No you can't. `.element` will be interpreted as looking for a property called `element`. FYI

Comment: Ah, you are right. I misunderstood the question. I was under the impression @WraithLux wanted to add an element attribute to his field object.

Answer (score 0):

if `element` is passed in as one of the names of the properties of field, this should work.

Try:

```
data['fields']['id'] = 1;
```

Maybe this would work?

Answer (score 0):

just a note, if you're dealing with arrays of objects, it would look more like this:

```
  var data = [{
        fields:[{
          id: 0,
          ticket: 0,
          description: "bar"
         },
         {
          id: 1,
          ticket: 1,
          description: "foo"
         }] 
  }];
```

then you could access the properties like

`data[0].fields[0].id`

`data[0].fields[1].description = "more foo"`

or

`data[0].fields[1]['description'] = "more foo"`